# Get Google Map KML data in JSON format

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, kml

Is there a way to get the KML file attached to this [Google Map](http://maps.google.co.uk/maps/ms?hl=en&ie=UTF8&vps=1&jsv=257c&oe=UTF8&authuser=0&msa=0&msid=202478852645429786800.00048bbce67ab330fa10f) in JSON format instead of XML?:

I'm currently writing an app that needs to load this KML data. I would prefer that it's in JSON format. Is there a way of getting it in this format?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since KML is just a flavor of XML, you could use any XML to JSON converter, of which there are many.

Here's one that's been around for a few years:
http://www.thomasfrank.se/xml_to_json.html

Comment: Thanks but I need to load this file programmatically every time my application loads so I make sure I have the latest version.

Comment: You mean like converting it to JSON on the fly? If so, maybe this would work? http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/wiki/JsonObjects

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to convert KML files to JSON and it was the most useful tool I found to do it programmatically

https://github.com/mapbox/togeojson#using-it-as-a-console-utility

It is with nodejs, you should do something like that in the cli

`togeojson file.kml > file.geojson`

Then, you can pass it into a json quite easy

Anyway, hope this help