# Getting a list of locations from a Google Map as JSON

Tags: iphone, json, google-maps

I have a created a [custom Google Map](https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msid=206707465380881466323.0004e072654e79ec3eb86&msa=0&ll=51.69299,-1.801758&spn=3.643526,9.876709) and I want to get the latitude and longitude in JSON after making an API request. The data is going to be used in an iPhone app. I've read this questions: [Get Google Map KML data in JSON format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8172184/get-google-map-kml-data-in-json-format) and through the Google Places API but I can't find a simple way to do this. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: did you take a look in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/ ?

Comment: I have. I am using their iOS library for mapping which is really helpful. I'm just trying to find a simple way for a client to add a list of locations on a web-based Google map and then get access to that data so I can add it to an iPhone app.